# Minify list of files without Entry point Webpack

Tags: webpack

With Webpack, we have entry kind of modal and it recursively bundle and minify all the files. But i want to just manually bundle list of files. The list can be some 4 to 5 plugins to 1 js file.

The way we do on Gulp, can we do this in Webpack.

This style i know how to do it, because we give the entry point

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {...},
  output: {...},
  module: {...},
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are 3rd party packages that you are trying to bundle, then using the CommonChunksPlugin is what you're looking for https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#manifest-file.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(env) {
    return {
        entry: {
            main: './index.js',
            vendor: ['moment', 'lodash', 'jQuery']
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: ['vendor', 'manifest'] // Specify the common bundle's name.
            })
        ]
    }
};
```

Add an array of package names to the vendor array and webpack will bundle those into their own chunk separate from your app files.